# ObjectDataSource vs new DomainDataSource

Tags: objectdatasource, domaindatasource

I don't see difference between ObjectDataSource and new DomainDataSource (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/04/11/using-domaindatasource-in-asp-net.aspx). 
I need create 4 methods, which is then used in both cases.

What I main difference?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'm aware of is that the ObjectDataSource doesn't work very well against "tracked" data objects. If the data object is, say, a Linq to SQL object then you need a Linq to SQL DataContext to be tracking that data object before it can be "updated" to the database. The ObjectDataSource relies on [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to build your data objects just before it tries to save them.

On an older VS2005 project I was on, we were using NHibernate as a backend (which similarly needs to be responsible for instantiating data objects) and ended up using a version of [this NHibernateDataSource](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NHibernateDataSource.aspx) on our aspx pages.

It seems that the DomainDataSource intends to be usable against all kinds of DataContext powered domain models objects (I'm not going to call them POCOs ;)), Linq to SQL, Linq to Entities, Astoria, RIA services etc...